# php rename() Access is denied. (code: 5)

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I am trying to use rename function in php.

On the first try, if the destination folder is empty or does not contain any directories with the same name as the source folder the rename function works perfectly. However, if there is same directory name it fails. What I want is just to overwrite it and I thought rename() would suffice.

Here is my code:

```
/**
        *   Move temp folders to their permanent places
        *
        *   $module_folder = example (violator, pnp, etc)       
        *   $folders = name of folders within module_folder
        **/
        public function move_temp_to_permanent($module_folder, $folders){
            $bool = false;

            $module_folder_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../public/resources/temps/' . $module_folder);

            $module_folder_destination_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ssmis/public/resources/photos/' . $module_folder . '/';

            foreach($folders as $folder){
                $bool = rename($module_folder_path . '/' . $folder, $module_folder_destination_path . $folder);
            }

            return $bool;
        }
```

The code above gives me an error saying:

> Message: 
>   rename(C:\xampp\htdocs\ssmis\public\resources\temps\violator/SJ-VIOL-2015-0002,C:/xampp/htdocs/ssmis/public/resources/photos/violator/SJ-VIOL-2015-0002):
>   Access is denied. (code: 5)

I am using CodeIgniter as framework.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check file permissions.

Comment: I was able to use rename() successfully as I've said above. But when I try to use it to move a folder from the source to the destination folder in which there is the same name as the resource then the error occurs. Do I still need to check file permissions since I was able to write on the directory?

Comment: you can not have folders with same name in a directory , you need to check for the same name and `merge` the contents if needed.

Comment: Is there a way to overwrite it or something?

Comment: don't know if this is the problem but you used mixed directory separators. maybe you should use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant and do realpath on both paths.

Comment: What you trying to do upload image or just rename folder name

Comment: I am trying to move folder with contents inside it

Comment: okk try with copy ($module_folder_path . '/' . $folder, $module_folder_destination_path . $folder);

Comment: Thanks for info guys. Really appreciated it What I do is to remove the directory containing the same name, then moving the source. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If it is on Windows, this can be read in contributions:

> rename() definitely does not follow the *nix rename convention on WinXP with PHP 5.  If the $newname exists, it will return FALSE and $oldname and $newname will remain in their original state.  You can do something like this instead:

```
function rename_win($oldfile,$newfile) {
    if (!rename($oldfile,$newfile)) {
        if (copy ($oldfile,$newfile)) {
            unlink($oldfile);
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php#56576).

Comment: this is what I've done to solve the problem. I delete the old file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding extra / in path make this like

```
/**
        *   Move temp folders to their permanent places
        *
        *   $module_folder = example (violator, pnp, etc)       
        *   $folders = name of folders within module_folder
        **/
        public function move_temp_to_permanent($module_folder, $folders){
            $bool = false;

            $module_folder_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../public/resources/temps/' . $module_folder);

            $module_folder_destination_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ssmis/public/resources/photos/' . $module_folder . '/';

            foreach($folders as $folder){
                $bool = rename($module_folder_path . $folder, $module_folder_destination_path . $folder);
            }

            return $bool;
        }
```

you can also echo the path you prepared so you can check its right or not

Answer (score 0):

Though its too Old post, Still answering if useful for anyone

If your Destination is directory name you will get this issue.
But if you specify the destination as directory + Filename it worked for me.

```
File::move(storage_path($file), storage_path('/destination'.basename($file)));
```