# How to rename folder using PHP?

Tags: php

is there a way for me to rename a folder using PHP?

I have a table name products inside my database and everytime there is a product inserted to that table, a folder is also created for that product (folder name depends on the product name inserted). Now on the editing end, how can I rename the folder if the user changed the product name.

I tried to use the rename method but it says: Access Denied. (code: 5).

Comment: Hello, Arjay. Welcome to StackOverflow. As noted by Nicolas, your question has already been asked and answered before. When you have this kind of problem, try Googling or even searching SO website for the language name, error code, error message, like: "php rename folder access denied code 5" gives you the answer you need right away. Cheers! o/

Comment: In addition to @CharlesFerreira answer, i would like to remind you to always check the [how to ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to create a complete and answerable question.

Comment: Hello! I appreciate your info. really helpful for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try php default function:

```
rename('OLd folder name', 'New folder name');
```

But One suggestion for your code of way.

You can use the product uniqueId for create directory or folder, so In edit,delete any functional case you will not face any issues.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have read and write permissions in the source folder

**Example:**

```
if(rename('old_name', 'new_name'))
{ 
    echo "Successfully Renamed";
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the suggestion. I already found the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077379/php-rename-access-is-denied-code-5