# Rename function don't work with folders in php

Tags: php, rename

This is my PHP code

```
<?php
rename(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/old', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/new');
?>
```

And I getting this error

**Warning: rename(C:\xampp\htdocs\goahead\php\old, C:\xampp\htdocs\goahead\php/new): Access is denied (code: 5) in C:\xampp\htdocs\goahead\php\test.php on line 3**

What is the problem?

Comment: Could you tell a bit more what your understanding of the diagnostic message _"Access is denied (code: 5)"_ is or what you read out of it?

Comment: I think there is a permission that I should enable in xampp, not sure

Comment: Yes, that could be. But there can be more reasons. For example that it is not possible to rename a folder, because the file system might also deny access to it for the rename operation _for folders_.

Comment: Well, is there any other functions that can rename the folder?

Comment: I don't know, but if you make a search for this exact error message you should also find some contributions for that error and also with the windows operating system. So you will likely find some more information more specifically, I don't have Windows at hand so I can not really answer it.

Comment: If you don't have permission to do the operation with the folder, another function isn't going to help (unless you can change the permissions).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php rename() Access is denied. (code: 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077379/php-rename-access-is-denied-code-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is php file doesn't have access to rename files make sure you run the web server as administrator (windows)

For Linux you will type this code in terminal

chmod 777 php_file.php

- EDIT *

If all of this doesn't work then go to properties in the file that need to be renamed then go to tab security and make sure that everyone user is added and can edit the file (windows)

In Linux you should check file owner and change it