# PHP rename() function not working properly. Alternative access is denied (code: 5)

Tags: php, rename

I am facing a strange situation with php **rename()** function. I download a file using API and then moved that file to destination folder.

> $download_path =
> C:\Users\JOHN\AppData\Local\Temp/downloaded_folder/downloaded_file.png
> $moving_path = C:\xampp\htdocs\project-1/images/downloaded_file.png

***Every time downloading is working perfectly and file downloaded***

The [rename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function is working alternatively. ie on first time it works second time fails.  3rd time ITS works 4th time fails etc.

ie first time file moved . and second time i am getting warning

> **Warning:**
> rename(C:\Users\JOHN\AppData\Local\Temp/downloaded_folder/downloaded_file.png,C:\xampp\htdocs\project-1/images/downloaded_file.png):
> **Access is denied (code: 5)**
> **Warning:** copy(C:\xampp\htdocs\project-1/images/downloaded_file.png):
> Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Please see my code below.

```
if (file_exists($moving_path)) {
   @unlink($moving_path);
}

if (file_exists($download_path) && !file_exists($moving_path)) {
    
    if (!rename($download_path, $moving_path)) {
            if (copy ($download_path, $moving_path)) {
                echo 'no rename but copied';
            } else {
                echo 'not moved';
            }
        } else {
             echo 'moved';
        }
    @rmdir(dirname($download_path))
}
```

Here what happen is **first time** it's moved and downloaded_file.png coming inside project-1/images folder  & **echo moved** and **second time** there is no file coming and **echo not moved** .

**Third time** downloaded_file.png coming inside project-1/images folder  & **echo moved** and **4th time** there is no file coming and **echo not moved**.

How to solve this issue. Please help. I seen a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077379/php-rename-access-is-denied-code-5) but that answer also not working for me

Comment: Start by taking out the `@` operator so that you can see what error messages PHP might be producing.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular thank you . Updated the question. I am getting Access is denied (code: 5) message.

Comment: PHP doesn't have access to the user's filesystem for security reasons. At least not from the browser.

Comment: Code: 5 is about [permission](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/system-error-code-5-access-is-denied/0d027ec1-553d-47cd-9be3-d9eed71013e5). However, I see this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077379/php-rename-access-is-denied-code-5) but I'm not sure does it work for you.

Comment: maybe php does not have permission to read file in ```C:\Users\JOHN\AppData\Local\Temp/downloaded_folder/downloaded_file.png``` since it's user's temp folder

Comment: but first time it is working. second time getting warning. third time it is working. 4th time getting warning.

Comment: @John Try to get [file permission](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) and [owner](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileowner.php) data every time and see if they are always same or different when showing warning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have the correct folder permissions for:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\project-1/images/

As you have this directory showing up in your error for the `rename` and the `copy` functions. Set this directory's permissions to 750, for your basic needs.

Since you're using windows:

Right Click>Properties>Security Tab
Change the permissions for your user the script is running under to "Read & execute" and "Write".